# zsh alias not recognizing : command not found

Tags: alias, zsh

Hellor everybody, i wanted to add an alias in my .zshrc file but please have a look at this i really don't understand

```
[23:29:36] charvet:~ $ expressvpn
NAME:
    expressvpn - ExpressVPN command line interface

USAGE:
    expressvpn command [arguments...]

VERSION:
    1.1.0 (e822d60)

COMMANDS:
    activate     Activate account
    connect      Connect to VPN
    disconnect   Disconnect from VPN
    status       Display service information
    list, ls     List VPN locations
    autoconnect  Enable / disable auto-connect
    protocol     Display / change preferred protocol
    refresh      Refresh VPN clusters
    reset        Reset VPN account
    diagnostics  Display connection diagnostics
    preferences  List user preferences
    help, h      Shows a list of commands or help for one command

 GLOBAL OPTIONS:
    --help, -h       show help
    --version, -v    print the version
```

Then i wrote in my file .zshrc

```
 alias expressvpn=vpn
```

Then in zsh :

```
 [23:29:46] charvet:~ $ source .zshrc
 ls='ls --color=tty'
 [23:29:52] charvet:~ $ vpn
 zsh: command not found: vpn
 [23:29:55] charvet:~ $
```

I am completely lost, i don't understand. People talk about the white space around the "=" but i haven't any.

Answer (score 3):

Try `alias vpn=expressvpn`?

Try `help alias` for help with alias syntax.

Comment: *zsh* does not have the `help` command. Information about builtins in *zsh* - like `alias` - can be found in `man zshbuiltins`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to say in your profile

```
alias expressvpn= 'vpn'
```

that's how it works